# Adding more fields to devise's new registration view causing ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, erb

I am very naive in using devise with rails. I just created default views for employees signup, and my table contains default devise user fields(such as password, email etc) along with my custom fields such as `first_name` and `last_name`. In the `new.html.erb` file, which was like this initially,

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email%>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "employees/shared/links" %>
```

I added two more text fields as:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name%>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email%>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "employees/shared/links" %>
```

but these two parameters, `first_name` and `last_name` are not being passed in the post call, since the error I get says:

```
PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column "first_name" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (6, null, null, null, prabhjotsinghrai1@gmail.com, $2a$11$KpJ4wnRfgeJ.N7hqnamiyOMpABXtPw0VppB1KBV6sL4fpJs3pTLCS, null, null, null, 0, null, null, null, null, 2017-02-05 14:00:44.450243, 2017-02-05 14:00:44.450243). : INSERT INTO "employees" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"
```

I see that the `first_name` and `last_name` are not being added to the `INSERT` query. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably faced the problem when the new attributes you've added to your model aren't permitted for mass assignment. If so you need to set up strong parameters for Devise with your `first_name` and `last_name` attributes like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name])
  end
end
```

See [Devise Strong Parameters](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters) for more info.

**P.S.** You may want to add validations for the presence of `first_name` and `last_name` for you could handle that errors better (instead of getting errors from Postgres)

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works! One question - why do i need to do this specifically for `first_name` and `last_name`? I added these fields myself after executing `rails generate devise employee` and adding the fields `t.string :first_name` `t.string :last_name` in the migration.

Comment: Apparently Devise handle its default attributes but if you add some by yourself (even using the same migration) you need to tell Devise to handle them too.